# Where will the tensorflow variable assignment really happen when assignment and placement are in different devices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am confused about the variable assignment and placement in tensorflow

If we create a variable in a certain device, for example in gpu0. while we will need to update the value for this variable in different device, for example in gpu2. where will the exact assignment happen?

```
def foo():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        x = tf.Variable(3, name='x')
    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
        y = tf.Variable(6, name='y')
    return x, y

x, y = foo()

with device("/gpu:2")  
    z1 = tf.assign(x, 1)    ---(1)
    z2 = tf.assign(y, 2)    ---(2)
    z3 = tf.multipy(x, y)   ---(3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(z1)
    sess.run(z2)
    sess.run(z3)
```

For the above example, my understanding is, z1/z2 will be happened on gpu2, but actually, x will be updated in gpu0, and y will be updated in gpu1. In --(3) gpu2 will fetch the x/y from gpu0 and gpu1 again and then complete in multiply ops in gpu2

please correct me if I were miss-understand something